# Can't Concatenate when assigning variable values

Tags: r, concatenation, variable-assignment

This seems elementary but I would like to get some understanding as to why this error is coming up.

longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

In Titanic dataset I'm trying to create a binary column if the passenger title is Reverend or not. There are 8 or so and I want to quickly do this by concatenating as follows:

```
titanic.full[titanic.full$PassengerId == c(150,151,250,627,849,887,1041,1056), 17] <- 1
```

This returns the error shown above. I can do the following:

```
titanic.full[titanic.full$PassengerId == 151, 17] <- 1
```

but concatenating seems to jam things up. Any idea on why this is happening would be much appreciated!

Comment: You want `%in%` here, not `==`. `titanic.full[titanic.full$PassengerId %in% c(150,151,250,627,849,887,1041,1056), 17] <- 1`

Comment: Thank you so much! I am not sure why it worked the way I did it if I assigned only one of the numbers, but not when I concatenated but at least you gave me the correction. thanks again.